# How do I use this Cordova Plugin? "Cordova Audio Stream Plugin" ?

Tags: cordova

I have been trying to figure out this for days, but I do not know why but I cannot seem to know how to use this plugin.  There is not much documentation on this github.

https://github.com/keosuofficial/cordova-audio-stream-plugin

*What I have done so far/tried*

I added the plugin via

cordova plugin add https://github.com/keosuofficial/cordova-audio-stream-plugin.git

I added stream.js in my index.html

I added this function my code

```
var my_stream = new Stream("http://audio.scdn.arkena.com/11689/goo_150739.mp3", onSuccess, onError);
// Play audio
my_stream.play();

function onSuccess() {
    console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
}

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

I receive an error

*undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Stream("http://audio.scdn.arkena.com/11689/goo_150739.mp3", onSuccess, onError)'), http://192.168.200.121:8100/js/app.js, Line: 14*

Comment: You just want to listen this audio file ? Why don't you use HTML5 <audio> tag ?

Comment: @BipBip I currently do use the audio tag at the moment, however Android has some a delays when using HTML Audio - That's why i'm trying to see if I can use native audio functionalities to see if that will be fixed

Comment: Plugin's `Stream.js` file has the `stream` constructor which is having `this.src` which will take your URL. But here it is returning undefined. So check out from your URL

Comment: Normally, the mp3 URL works fine

Comment: Did you find any resolve this problem ? I've this error Uncaught module org.apache.cordova.media.Media not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:59